# Special char app name ❤ and Apple validation

Tags: ios, app-store

I would add the special char ❤ in the app name in device.
But no special char in the iTunes App name.

Do you think apple will approve my app?

Thank

**EDIT: No Problem in the App name on the device ;).**

Comment: Doesn't hurt to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UTF-8 chars like that in your app name, but I don't think it will show up in appstore though. It will definitely show up under the launcher icon as a pictogram i think. Check out the app "Tom's Love Letters" for an example.

Take a look somewhere inside `Edit->Special Characters` in Xcode.